# What does `_parse_section` of `kurfile.py` do?

Tags: python, deep-learning

run `kur dump cifar.yml` in console, when the code execute at `kurfile.Kurfile.parse()`, in debug mode:

Before and after [L115](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/kurfile.py#L115)

```
self._parse_section(
    self.engine, builtin['settings'], stack, include_key=False,
    auto_scope=True)
```

There is no difference to the output of `pprint(self.__dict__['data']['settings'])`, so what is the actual use of `_parse_section` here?

Before and after

```
self._parse_section(
    self.engine, builtin['train'], stack, include_key=False,
    auto_scope=True)
```

There is no difference to the output of `pprint(self.__dict__['data']['train'])`. The only effect I observe is that we can now run `pprint(self.__dict__['data']['training'])` with the same output.  so what are the actual uses of `_parse_section` here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @ajsyp:

> `_parse_section`. The job of this call is to use the Engine to evaluate any Jinja2 templating. In the CIFAR example, there isn't any Jinja2 templating used *anywhere* in the Kurfile---except for the `model` section, which is handled very specially---so you can expect no changes to the `data` dictionary before/after the call.